# focus select (HTML Element) using javascript without opening it

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, focus

i am trying to focus a select (aka drop-down) using javascript, so that the user can press enter if he wants to open it. I expected .focus() to do the trick here but it also opens the select, which I dont want. I am looking for the same state as tab selecting it.

hope you can help me :)

Comment: Show how you are doing it is working fine for me

Comment: have a look at [autofocus](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_autofocus.asp)

Comment: @brk yeah, you are right, found my problem (I think) - the same event that triggered the .focus() also opened the select